# How to enable Guest Checkout with Payum for Symfony for a Swiss account?

Tags: symfony, payum

How to enable Guest Checkout with [Payum for Symfony](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/get-it-started.md) for a Swiss account? I am using Payum to handle payments in a website. The problem is that with Express Checkout feature as it's illustrated [there](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/custom-purchase-examples/paypal-express-checkout.md) :

```
<?php
//src/Acme/PaymentBundle/Controller
namespace AcmeDemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPaymentAction()
    {
        $gatewayName = 'your_gateway_name';

        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails');

        /** @var \Acme\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails $details */
        $details = $storage->create();
        $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
        $details['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 1.23;
        $storage->update($details);

        $captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
            $gatewayName,
            $details,
            'acme_payment_done' // the route to redirect after capture;
        );

        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    }
}
```

the Guest Checkout is not enabled.

Comment: What do you mean by guest checkout?

Comment: @MaksimKotlyar, the ability for customers to pay with credit card and without a PayPal account

Comment: That's currently supported, You just have to set proper info to payment details. Check the Paypal docs.